# Why sometimes my UIBarButton is bold and sometimes it's thin

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

[image]

[image]

I didn't remember setting this anywhere.

Comment: Used attributed string or any thing like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain system bar buttons, such as "Save" and "Done" have bold font to signal the action to the user. They used to be buttons with darker background, but now only the font is differnet.